# ターミナルを起動するとzsh: command not found: -zshが毎回表示される

Tags: macos

ターミナルを起動した際、「zsh」に変更するようアナウンスされたので、
「システム環境設定」→「ユーザとグループ」→「詳細オプション」→「管理者」をcontrol+クリック→ログインシェルを/bin/zshに変更しました。

その後、ターミナルを起動する度に下記のような表示がされるのですが、問題ないのでしょうか。
解決策を色々と調べてみたのですが、答えに辿り着かず、数時間経過しております。
手助けいただけると幸いです。

#### ターミナル起動時の表示コード

```
Last login: Fri May 21 09:13:24 on console
xxxxx@xxxxxMacBook-Air ~ % -zsh
zsh: command not found: -zsh
```

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
zsh: command not found: -zsh
```

#### 試したこと

- PCの再起動
- Homeディレクトリの「bash_profile」に記載されているコードを、「zshrc」ファイルにコピー

.bash_profile

```
source ~/.profile
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

.zshrc

```
export PATH=$HOME/.nodebrew/current/bin:$PATH
source ~/.profile
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

#### 実行環境

macOS Catalina(バージョン 10.15.7)

Comment: `.bash_prifile`からコピーした`.zshrc`に何が書いてあるかに依りますので、質問に`.zshrc`の内容を書き加えて頂くと回答が付きやすいかと思います。　多分ですが、`.zshrc`の中に`-zsh`を含んだ行がありそうなので、それを適宜書き替えると直るとは思うのですが

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
ファイルの中身を追記しました。
-zshが含まれた記載はありませんでした

Comment: `source` コマンドで読み込んでいる `~/.profile` ファイルの中身も同様に確認してみてください。

Comment: sourceコマンドで読み込んでいる ~/.profile ファイルの場所を見つけられませんでした。。もう少し勉強してから再度挑戦してみようと思います。コメントいただきましてありがとうございました。

Comment: `~/.profile`はhomeディレクトリの下の`.profile`というファイルです。同様に質問に追加頂ければと思います。